# VLSM assistance

Tags: networking, cisco

I have a quick query about using VLSM. I need to adopt a optimized addressing scheme making use of VLSM, I have 3 networks in total connected via two different routers, router 1 has a network of 300 hosts and another network of 25 hosts. Router 1 is connected to router 2 and that has an additional 82 hosts. Would it be possible to do this scheme over two IP addresses?

Lets say my starting IP is 182.20.1.0, how would this work?

Answer (score 0):

You would at least need 4 subnets (between router 1 and 2 you need a /30 subnet). You need to reserve ip addresses for each subnet starting from the subnet with the highest number of hosts.

The number of hosts determines how big your subnets will be. You can have (2^n-2) host for every subnet, having n the number of reserved bits.

So for your first subnet you'll need 9 bits, leaving you with a /23 subnet.

Start over for your next subnet with the next available ip address.